# What do the absolute value bars mean in graph theory?

Tags: notation

Just wanted to know, for example in the wikipedia page [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) what the absolute value bars meant in `O(|E| + |V|log|V|)`

Comment: sizeof ...............

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vertical bars indicate the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) (or size) of a set. In the case of Dijkstra's algorithm, `|E|` is the number of edges and `|V|` is the number of vertices.

Comment: Why are these only used in graph theory?  Cardinality just refers to the number of items in a set so why doesn't it apply to lists and arrays too?  You never see O(|n|), but rather O(n).

Comment: I don't think the premise is correct that vertical bars are exclusive to set theory. You also see them for other kinds of "size" in other contexts. For instance `|V|` is the magnitude of a vector `V`, and `|x|` is the absolute value of the number `x`. Those aren't quite the same as cardinality, but the concepts are pretty closely related. As for `O(n)`, usually `n` is already the size of some set, not the set itself. Formally it might be written as "`O(n)` for `n=|A|`" (if `A` is an array or other data structure). In informal contexts, people are often very sloppy about defining `n`.